# GCR using CLI to retrieve tagless images

Tags: gcloud, google-container-registry, gcloud-cli

I know you can do the following to retrieve a list of tags of a specific image:

> gcloud container images list --repository=gcr.io/myproject

But I was wondering whether I can also use the gcloud CLI to retrieve the images without a tag.

The tag-less images are shown in the Google cloud console web interface.

**Solution**

> gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/myproject/repo --filter='-tags:*'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list-tags` would be better for your needs. Specifically, if you want to see information on all images (including untagged ones):

`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project-id/repository --format=json`

And if you want to print the digests of images which are untagged:

`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project-id/repository --filter='-tags:*' --format='get(digest)' --limit=$BIG_NUMBER`

Comment: The first command doesn't give me the untagged images, but the `--filter='-tags:*'` part did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [list-tags](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#listing_image_tags_and_digests) sub-command:

```
gcloud container images list-tags --repository=gcr.io/myproject/myrepo
```